# How to relabel scraping jobs on Prometheus-operator?

Tags: kubernetes, label, prometheus, prometheus-operator

I'm trying the prometheus-operator for the first time, and still struggling with the differences for managing Prometheus through that.

The deployment is pretty straight-forward, and so is editing the rules, however I could not find my way when trying to relabel the exporters using `static_configs` when using Prometheus-operator.

What I used to do in the past was to customize `prometheus.yml` and add `static_configs` to include the labels for each one of the exporter's job names.

I understand that under Prometheus-operator's hood we have the same settings as we usually have,  but I'm not sure how to achieve the same results from the `static_config` configuration using the operator.

From what I could understand I have to do set the relabelings now on the service monitors related to my exporters, however all the configurations I've tried had no results:

tried with `metricRelabelings` as descirbed on issue [1166](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/issues/1166), and `StaticConfigs` as described on [issue 1086](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/issues/1086) without any luck.

For example this is what I used to do for `kubernetes-cadvisor` exporter to set a label on `static_config`, so that my custom label was displayed on all the metrics collected by my exporters on ingestion time:

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: prometheus
static_configs:
- targets: ['localhost:9090']
labels:
kubernetes_namespace: kube-system
cluster_name: mycluster01
```

And also add the `relabel_configs` on each of my exporters job's:

```
- job_name: 'kubernetes-cadvisor'
scheme: https
tls_config:
  ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
kubernetes_sd_configs:
- role: node
relabel_configs:
  - target_label: cluster_name
    replacement: mycluster01
  - target_label: kubernetes_namespace
    replacement: kube-system
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
  - target_label: __address__
    replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
    regex: (.+)
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}:10250/proxy/metrics
```

And this is an example for achieving the same using `metricRelabelings`, on Prometheus-operator which is still not working for me:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: node-exporter
  name: node-exporter
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  endpoints:
  - bearerTokenFile: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
    interval: 30s
    port: https
    scheme: https
    tlsConfig:
      insecureSkipVerify: true
  jobLabel: k8s-app
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: node-exporter
  metricRelabelings:
    sourceLabels: __meta_kubernetes_node_name
    targetLabel: node
```

What I expect to achieve is to create a static label on my exporters so all the metrics carry the custom label that I define at the scraping time instead of having to manually define custom labels to all the deployments in my cluster.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems I've missed the instructions in the Operator repository.... After a closer look there I've found some very nice examples... seems the answer to my question is to create the additional scraping configuration as a secret, similar to the example at the following link: [additional-scrape-configs.yaml](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/example/additional-scrape-configs/additional-scrape-configs.yaml)

Some additional steps can also be found at the following: [additional-scrape-config](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/additional-scrape-config.md)

Comment: Can we add a label like (env=dev) for all the metrices coming from a servicemonitor using additional scrape settings..?

Answer (score 2):

Let's see on example how it works. First, deploy four instances of example application, which listens and exposes metrics on port 8080.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-application
spec:
  replicas: 4
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example-application
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: example-application
        image: fabxc/instrumented_app
        ports:
        - name: backend
          containerPort: 8080
```

The ServiceMonitor has a label selector to select Services and their underlying Endpoint objects. The Service object for the example application selects the Pods by the app label having the example-application value. The Service object also specifies the port on which the metrics are exposed.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: example-application
  labels:
    app: example-application
spec:
  selector:
    app: example-application
  ports:
  - name: backend
    port: 8080
```

This Service object is discovered by a ServiceMonitor, which selects in the same way. The app label must have the value example-application.

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: example-application
  labels:
    team: backend-team
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example-application
  endpoints:
  - port: backend
```

Prometheus object defines the serviceMonitorSelector to specify which ServiceMonitors should be included. Above the label `team: backend-team` was specified, so that's what the Prometheus object selects by.

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  name: prometheus
spec:
  serviceMonitorSelector:
    matchLabels:
      team: backend-team
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 400Mi
```

This enables the backend team to create new ServiceMonitors and Services which allow Prometheus to be dynamically reconfigured.

You can also look on [this site](https://coreos.com/blog/the-prometheus-operator.html) to read more informations about ServiceMonitor in Prometheus Operator.

Comment: Hi @abielak, thanks for the thorough answer, but my problem is how to add metric labels on ingestion time, without the operator I could just modify the scraping settings in `prometheus.yml`. Found in the repository the right documentation to do it.... seems one has to add the additional scraping configs as a secret now, as described at the [operator documentation](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/example/additional-scrape-configs/additional-scrape-configs.yaml). But again, thanks a lot for the help!